# I need add other component with this button

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

this button component's, I need to click and pull another component with it, but I don't know how to do that, look at the return *plantioComp*, this is the component I want this button to call.

```
<template>
        <div class="btn-center">
        <v-btn class="mx-1" fab dark v-on:click="propri" type="submit">
          <v-icon dark> mdi-plus </v-icon>
          <p class="text-btn">Plantio</p>
        </v-btn>
        </div>
    </template>



 <script>
    import plantioComp from './plantioComp.vue'
    
    export default {
      name: 'btnAdd',
      methods: {
        propri () {
        //   alert('here')
          return plantioComp
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the button element to plantioComp when click?

Comment: @Kurt that's almost it, but with each click on the button I duplicate the plantingComp component., showing it over and over on the screen

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by calling another component on click or what plantioComp is.  I assume you mean to make the component displayed? If so, it needs to be added to the template.  If you have a condition where it needs to display only after a button click, you can create a boolean data variable that is initially false and then set to true on button click.  Using a v-if directive on plantioComp you can  have it display once the variable is true.

```
<template>
        <div class="btn-center">
        <v-btn class="mx-1" fab dark v-on:click="showPlantio=true" type="submit">
          <v-icon dark> mdi-plus </v-icon>
          <p class="text-btn">Plantio</p>
        </v-btn>
        </div>
        <plantioComp v-if="showPlantio" />
    </template>



 <script>
    import plantioComp from './plantioComp.vue'
    
    export default {
      name: 'btnAdd',
      data() {
        return {
            showPlantio: false
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

I think your app is using vuetify.  If you are specifically trying to show a modal, I would suggest using the [v-dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/) component.